# How to duplicate content approval kind of thing in sharepoint 2013, as there is no publishing feature in sharepoint 2013 foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

My requirement is for content approval kind of feature in sharepoint 2013 foundation, so that only the approved document should be visible to users.

Answer (score 0):

As you know OOTB publishing is not available for SPF, so you have to try below codeplex solution( a great success)

> The SharePoint Server comes with a Publishing feature as an out of the
>   box component so that you can use its rich functionalities to build
>   and deploy custom branded sites using master pages, layout pages etc.
>   These functionalities are not available out of the box in SharePoint
>   Foundation.
>
> The SharePoint Foundation 2013 Publishing Infrastructure aims at
>   bringing a stripped down version of the SharePoint Server Publishing
>   functionality to SharePoint Foundation 2013. It provides the site
>   publishing features to the SharePoint Foundation platform. By using
>   its features one can easily create and maintain a custom branded site
>   using SharePoint Designer in SharePoint Foundation.

[SharePoint Foundation 2013 Publishing Infrastructure](https://spf2013publishing.codeplex.com/)